Downloading administrative boundaries from OpenHistoricalMap
I found that someone already published administrative historical boundaries I'm interested in. It is available on the OpenHistoricalMap project, part of OpenStreetMap. Here is the link for one of the layers I'm interested in.
How would I download the boundaries of "District IV. Szluiner Regiment No. 63" as a shapefile or something I can import and use in QGIS?

The approach Import single OSM feature XML into QGIS 3 works if you replace the site name with the OpenHistorical site name and get the "full" osm xml file. So download:
https://www.openhistoricalmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2747734/full
(where 2747734 is the ID of the relation you have found)
Rename as area.osm or whatever, then load into QGIS, selecting points, lines, polygons from the popup.


For completeness, here’s some documentation about what this API call includes: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Full:GET/api/0.6/%5Bway%7Crelation%5D/%23id/full
